# whenever click on next page it gives error page not found

Tags: wordpress

this is the link of my site every time I click on next page it shows page not found what to do

`http://couponsgrabber.in`

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Please check the .htaccess file. Also look for Permalinks structure in the options settings

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .htaccess file. It should contain a rewrite rule to enable pagination with slashes.

Please see: "Using pretty permalinks" - http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Also it could be possible that inside the `WP_Query` options, the

```
'paged'          => $paged
```

is not there

Comment: this is the .htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>